# Intuition and the reason behind rotation operators or angular momentum operators NOT commuting?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, commutator, intuition

So I was thinking about the fundamental reason why rotation operators don't commute so I started thinking about Euler rotations. I tried the experiment of the rotating frame, first around the x-axis then the y-axis; and the other around the y-axis then the x-axis.

The difference in the directions of a vector in z direction after these two rotations were not the supposed z, according to the equation in quantum mechanics $\left[L_i, L_j\right]=i \hbar \epsilon_{i j k} L_k$.

I tried searching everywhere, and the closest intuitive answers I got were on this link :
https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-Euler-angles-commute-It-makes-sense-that-the-rotation-matrices-wont-commute-but-when-I-try-the-rotations-on-an-object-in-real-life-it-seems-like-the-3-rotations-could-be-carried-in-any-order

But even though I couldn't find the answer to how is the commutation equal to the third component according to the above equation.

So that's my question. Any answers are appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Do you get that $x_i$ and $p_i$ do not commute? it follows that $L_i$ and $L_j$ do not commute for $i\neq j$. You can prove it by writing explicitly $L_k=\epsilon_{ijk}x_ip_j$ ($\mathbf L = \mathbf r \times \mathbf p$).

Comment: Related question on Math.SE: [Why is the product of two rotation matrices not commutative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2016937/11127)

Comment: @ Mauricio Yes, I know that derivation well. I was asking for the intuitive idea.

Comment: @Qmechanic I have seen that post already, but it nowhere explains that the difference of xy and yx operations turns out to be z. That is what I was asking

Comment: Have you done the small rotations on a sphere in different orders, subtract the two outcomes, and understood the answer?